# if with exit 0 & 1 and showing process

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I want to solve a certain task with a bash script which I pass to a parameter, but unfortunately I don't get anywhere.

This is what it is about.

If a user exists, the exit status 0 should be returned and displayed. If this user does not exist then 1. This works fine so far. Now it is so that if the user should exist and has running processes, only the processes should be displayed. Otherwise only the exit status 0 if the user exists and has no running processes.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
user=$1                                                                                                                     
exists=$(grep -c $user /etc/passwd)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

if [ "$exists" -ne 0 ]; then                                                                                                               
   echo $?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
else 
  echo $?                                                                                                                    
fi
```

I added an additional elif, but that did not work. How can I customize the script to show me the running processes for an existing user if they should exist or if no running processes exist but the user exists only returns and displays the status 0 or 1?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you remove the requirement that you print the 0 or the 1, which is not really necessary, your script can just be `grep -q "$1" /etc/passwd` (If you accept the premise that `grep`ing /etc/passwd is adequate)

Comment: First of all, your method to determine whether a user exists is flawed: For instance, `grep -c bash /etc/passwd` may print out a value greater than zero but likely there isn't a user named "bash". A simple method to determine this: `if id "$1" &>/dev/null; then echo "User '$1' exists"; else echo "User '$1' doesn't exist"; fi`

Comment: Perhaps try `id "$user" > /dev/null 2>&1 && ps -u "$user"`.  Not sure if this will suffice for users managed by LDAP.

Comment: Does the user you're running as have permission to see the processes of other users?  Run `top -u SOME_OTHER_USER` to confirm before you try writing a script to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` command can tell if user exists, without need to tap the `passwd` file, and works regardless of what resource type is providing the users database to the system.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

if id --user "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1;
then
  ps --user "$1" --format pid=,comm= || :
else
  false
fi
```

Or a one-liner:

```bash
sh -c 'id -u "$1">/dev/null 2>&1&&{ ps -u "$1" -o pid=,comm=||:;}' sh username
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` returns the exit status you are looking for, so you probably just want:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
user=$1                                                                                                                     
if grep -q "$user" /etc/passwd; then
    echo 0; 
    exit 0;
else
    echo 1;
    exit 1;
fi
```

But that's quite redundant and could be more easily written:

```
grep -q "$user" /etc/passwd
rv=$?
echo "$rv"
exit "$rv"
```

However, the requirement to print the return status is odd, and if you simply drop that, your script can just be the `grep`.

Note that this completely disregards that fact that `grep`ping /etc/password for the user name is not an adequate test to determine if the user exists, but that does not seem to be the heart of this question.

Comment: Thanks for that! The part about the exit status works so far and in ur way more easy. I got the problem with processes. If the user exist and got running processes, they should be displayed (and not the exit status). If the user exist and got no running processes, only the exit status 0 should be displayed. And when the user does not exist ofc only 1.

Comment: When you have user `william`, your search for `will` and `liam` should fail: `grep "^${user}:"`.